# How to get more than 100 restaurants via zomato api?

Tags: node.js, zomato-api

Firstly, I obtain a zomato api. Then I use nodejs fetch to get restaurants from the api.

0-19 items:

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=0&count=20
```

20-40 items:

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=20&count=20
```

40-60 items:

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=40&count=20
```

60-80 items:

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=60&count=20
```

80-100 items:

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=80&count=20
```

100-120 (from onward, it starts to return empty records)

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=100&count=20
```

My question is that is it a way to return more items.

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit is restricted to 100 results for a particular search criterion. There is no way to obtain more than 100 listings through search API (this is applicable to both basic and partner API access).

Comment: Is it a way to get more results (by other means)?

Comment: No, the functionality is not available yet.